# RegionDifference of a sphere and pyramid - Not correctly specified

Tags: graphics3d, regions, stl-format

I would like to cut out a pyramid from the sphere with the following but somehow I am missing something due to an error "RegionDifference object is not a correctly specified region"
Ultimately I would like to export this as an stl file.

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 1}], 
Pyramid[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}]}]

reg1 = Graphics3D[
Pyramid[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}]]

reg2 = Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 1}]]

rr = RegionDifference[reg2, reg1];

RegionPlot3D[rr, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) and [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) are not regions. The primitives (e.g., [`Pyramid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pyramid.html), [`Sphere`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sphere.html), [`Ball`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ball.html)) are regions. A `Sphere` is just the thin shell, the filled-in solid object is a `Ball`. Since you are cutting the `Pyramid` out, I assume that you mean `Ball` rather than `Sphere`.

```
reg1 = Pyramid[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}];

reg2 = Ball[{0, 0, 1}];
```

The argument to [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html) must be a boolean predicate describing the region rather than a region.

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Element[{x, y, z}, reg2] && ! Element[{x, y, z}, reg1],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.67],
 PlotPoints -> 35,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

```
rr = RegionDifference[reg2, reg1];

Region[Style[rr, Opacity[0.67]],
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarity!